# SQL query with Left Join to return results when the top 1 column of joined table matches column of main table

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have a main table (TableA) and I'm Left Joining TableB, but I only want to include the first record of TableB where ColumnB of the two tables match. I've gotten this to work in the query below, except I also need to include the records of TableA where no matching record exists for TableB (i.e. in the query below b.ColumnA would be null). I understand why my line below "OR b.ColumnA = null" does not work, but I'm struggling to find a solution that does.

Any reasonable way to ALSO include records of TableA where no matching records exist in TableB

```
SELECT b.ColumnA, a.ColumnA, a.ColumnB
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON b.ColumnB = a.ColumnB
WHERE b.ColumnA = (SELECT TOP 1 bb.ColumnA FROM TableA aa LEFT JOIN TableB bb ON bb.ColumnB = a.ColumnB)
OR b.ColumnA = null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT b.ColumnA, a.ColumnA, a.ColumnB
FROM TableA a OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) b.*
      FROM TableB b 
      WHERE b.ColumnB = a.ColumnB
      ORDER BY ?  -- however you are defining the ordering for "first"
     ) b;
```

You can leave out the `ORDER BY` if you are content with an *arbitrary* matching record from `b`.  However, the question specifies "first" without defining it.

Comment: That worked like a charm. I added WHERE and ORDER BY statements after the OUTER APPLY and it worked well. Thank you.

Comment: Also... I did not order within the OUTER APPLY, because in our case if there is more than one match, it is an error, so I need to arbitrarily select one.